# How I can create a addition Tree Editor with GEF?

Tags: editor, tree, palette, eclipse-gef

I have a graphical editor with GEF. It's possible to add objects from a palette.
An Example what I mean is this:
http://java-eclipse.info/IBM.Redbooks-Eclipse.Development.using.the.Graphical.Editing.Framework.and.the.Eclipse.Modeling.Framework/7823/images/fig166_01_0.jpg
So, now I want add a different possibility to display the content from the editor, in a tree view. I have found the possibility "Outline". It's work very well except for adding objects from the palette to the tree view. My goal is, that the graphical editor and the tree viewer/editor do the same things (add/delete objects, rename objects, changing properties from objects, ...), but show in a different way.
Is there a way?

Thanks for your helping!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add a Drop listener to the treeview in the outline and to implement accordingly all the edit policies created in the tree edit parts.